# Python PIL and StringIO

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to download images from URLs and pass them to PIL.

I would like to use as few resources as possible, especially RAM. What would the best way of dealing with this? I've had suggestions to use cStringIO.

Comment: what would you like to do with them? Could you sketch the process?

Comment: @extraneon: thanks for asking! I'm trying to download images from a webpage, check the sizes of each image on the page through PIL, choose the best one, thumbnail it and upload it to Amazon S3. This is the whole process ^^.

Comment: have you considered splitting the process a program to download the sets to a temp directory, and another program to process these downloads? Generally disk space is a bit less of a problem than RAM, and outgoing bandwidth tends to be more precious than incoming. That's probably easier balanced with 2 separate scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately file-likes from network functions such as `urllib2.urlopen()` don't support all the necessary methods, so you'll need to read the data into a `StringIO` or `cStringIO` in order to be able to pass them to `Image.open()`.

Comment: I had the same question, and this answer is consistently coming up again and again. Seems like StringIO is the way to go, then!